# Ruby, Tempfile, CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, temporary-files

I have the below resque job that produces a csv file and sends it to a mailer. I want to validate that the csv file has data so I do not email blank files. For some reason, when I write a method outside of the perform method, it will not work. For example, the below code will print invalid when I know the csv file has data on the first line. If I uncomment the line below ensure it works properly, however I want to extract this checking of the file into a separate method. Is this correct?

```
class ReportJob
  @queue = :report_job

def self.perform(application_id, current_user_id)
 user = User.find(current_user_id)
 client_application = Application.find(client_application_id)
 transactions = application.transactions
 file = Tempfile.open(["#{Rails.root}/tmp/", ".csv"]) do |csv|
   begin
     csv_file = CSV.new(csv)
     csv_file << ["Application", "Price", "Tax"]
     transactions.each do |transaction|
       csv_file << [application.name, transaction.price, transaction.tax]
     end
   ensure
    ReportJob.email_report(user.email, csv_file)
    #ReportMailer.send_report(user.email, csv_file).deliver
     csv_file.close(unlink=true)
   end
 end
end

 def self.email_report(email, csv)
   array = csv.to_a
   if array[1].blank?
     puts "invalid"
   else
     ReportMailer.send_report(email, csv).deliver
   end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke your method as such:

```
ReportJob.email_report(email, csv)
```

Otherwise, get rid of the `self` in:

```
def self.email_report(email, csv)
   # your implementation here.
end
```

and define your method as follows:

```
def email_report(email, csv)
  # your implementation.
end
```

This is something that we call Class Methods and Instance Methods.

Comment: Thanks- I tried invoking it as you said and it seems that the block is finishing before the method has a chance to go through the file. I am wondering if this is something to do with the tempfile class?